# Payload metadata is not created automatically for which connector endpoints?

Tags: mule, metadata, connector, payload

Among connector endpoints like File, Web Service Consumer, Database, HTTP Request which connector doesn't have payload metadata created for them?

Answer (score 0):

For Http and File Connectors you have metadata and based on the position of the message processor in the flow you can configure input or output payload.
But for Database and Web Service Consumer you can't find the Metadata, seems its done automatically.

Comment: @leo_roar_001: Hope you answered correctly in the exam! :)

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP Request and File connector payload metadata is not automatically created. For Web Service and Database connectors payload metadata is automatically created.